# How to implement the functionality in cytoscape.js to add an edge between two nodes by clicking the nodes?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I want to connect two nodes when the user clicks one node first and then the second node.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [cy.bind()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/events) function. You can bind the click event on a node and save the id of this node in an array for example:

```
cy.unbind('click');          // unbind event to prevent the event to fire 

cy.bind('click ', 'node', function (evt) { 
    // add the node to an array (node is in evt.target())
    // if there are 2 nodes in the array, remove them after creating an edge between them
    cy.add(//your new edge);
    array.splice(0, 2);   // remove the first 2 elements of your array
});
```

Comment: I cannot access anything outside the bind function from inside the bind function. If I initialise an array outside the bind function, it becomes undefined inside the bind function and hence I am unable to add any nodes to it.

Comment: Of course you can, just make a global variable and use that array to add your nodes, that is no problem normally :)